# Update/merge single value in group by where all columns have identical values in each group

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a data quality task where I need to allow one row in each group to remain unchanged, and then update the 'duplicate' column in the Delta table for the rest of the rows in the group to 'true'. Initially, when the data is loaded into the table, all values in the 'duplicate' column are 'false'.

The data is stored in Delta format and I am using Spark in Databricks.

An example would be that below. I then want to run a query which updates the 'duplicate' column for all rows in a group to 'true' and leaves only a single value as 'false'. This is so a downstream pipeline can still pick up one of the values where we have duplicates for downstream processing.

The table starts out like this:

| ID | Value1 | Value2 | Duplicate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | a | b | false |
| 23 | a | b | false |
| 24 | c | d | false |
| 25 | e | f | false |
| 26 | g | h | false |
| 26 | g | h | false |

and I need to end up with this:

| ID | Value1 | Value2 | Duplicate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | a | b | false |
| 23 | a | b | true |
| 24 | c | d | false |
| 25 | e | f | false |
| 26 | g | h | false |
| 26 | g | h | true |

I could of course simply say `spark.table("myTable").dropDuplicates()` but I would like to assess how big the issue is with duplicates as an external supplier provides data and we need to understand if there are excessive retries on the system which push up costs.

I am struggling to find a way to change all but one entry where I do not have any unique identifier to use. I have tried many different ways, but have failed. I have included what I would like to achieve below (this will clearly fail).

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 
    ID, 
    Duplicate,
    row_number() over (partition by ID) AS rn,
  FROM myTable
)
UPDATE myTable SET Duplicate = 'true' WHERE (SELECT rn FROM CTE) > 1
```

I am unsure if this is even possible without having some unique identifier. If possible I would like to try and avoid using any non-deterministic hashes just to accomplish this as the dataset is very large.

I can use any of Scala, PySpark or SQL within Spark so language isn't vital.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL, something like this should do the trick.

```
WITH duplicates
AS (
SELECT 
    ID,
    Duplicate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS rn
FROM
    myTable
)
UPDATE duplicates
SET Duplicate = 'false'
WHERE rn > 1
```

Comment: Thanks SDC. Unfortunately, I get this error back "Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: UPDATE destination only supports Delta sources." I thought this was the one but seems Spark doesnt support this style (I saw a similar post for SQL Server and it seemed to work for them).

Answer (score 0):

In pyspark you can try with row_number as below

```
df1.withColumn("rank",row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("ID"))).withColumn("duplicate",when(col("rank")>1,True).otherwise(False)).drop("rank").show()

#output
+---+------+------+---------+
| Id|value1|value2|duplicate|
+---+------+------+---------+
| 23|     a|     b|    false|
| 23|     a|     b|     true|
| 24|     c|     d|    false|
| 25|     e|     f|    false|
| 26|     g|     h|    false|
| 26|     g|     h|     true|
+---+------+------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was hoping there would be a way to update the table through an update or merge command. This works but I will need to overwrite the Delta table.

Comment: You can try adding rank column updating duplicate based on it and then dropping rank column in delta table itself